# Need countereample : If a sequence $(a_n) \in l^2 $ , then the sequence $(1/a_n) \notin l^2 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I want to know the counterexample for the following statement : 
Given a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_i\ne 0 $ for any $i$ :  If the sequence $(a_n) \in l^2 $ , then the sequence $(1/a_n) \notin l^2$.

Comment: suppose both $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\} = \bigg\{\frac{1}{a_n}\bigg\}$ are in $l^2$, we have $$\bigg(\sum a_i b_i \bigg)^2 \leq \bigg(\sum a_i^2 \bigg)\bigg(\sum b_i^2 \bigg).$$

Comment: @Xiao So, if we substitute $b_n=1/a_n$ we get a contradiction and so there exists no counterexample ?

Comment: I don't think there exists a counterexample.

Comment: @Xiao I actually want to know if $(a_n)\in l^2 $ and $(b_n)\in l^2$, can we say that $\sum a_nb_n \in l^2 $ ?

Comment: $\sum a_n b_n \in l^1$ from the inequality above, and by convexity, we have $$ \sum (a_n b_n)^2 \leq \bigg(\sum |a_n b_n|\bigg) ^2 < \infty.$$ So yes, $\{a_n b_n\} \in l^2$.

Comment: If $(a_n)$ is in $\ell^2$ then $(a_n)$ is **bounded** hence, for every $(b_n)$ in $\ell^2$, $(a_nb_n)$ is in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Unrelated: the assertion that $\sum a_nb_n$ is in $\ell^2$ or in $\ell^1$ is absurd since each $\ell^p$ is a space of sequences, not of series.

Comment: @Did I'm sorry. I meant $(a_n b_n)$ and not the sum.

Answer (score 6):

If $a\in\ell^2$, then $a_n\to0$. Thus $1/a_n\not\to0$, which prevents it from being in $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\left(\sum_{\nu =1}^n 1\right)^2=n^2\leqslant \sum_{\nu=1}^n a_\nu^2\sum_{\nu =1}^n a_\nu^{-2}$$

This gives a pretty rough estimate of how the sum of the squares of the reciprocals diverge. Of course the simplest is Martin's approach.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more ? I'm not able to understand how to apply Cauchy Schwartz here .

Answer (score -1):

Put $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$.
Then $ \sum \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$,finite.

But $\sum n^2$ is not in $l^2$.